# AppleScript: Watch a folder and notify when changes stop

Tags: applescript

I have a scanner that does batch operations. I want to have a script that send me a notification (simple email will do) that no more images have been added to a folder after a certain time limit - say 90 seconds.

Can someone help me with the basic structure?  This machine is locked on OS X Lion for context.

Comment: Is this going to be started by a folder action?  What have you done so far?

Comment: Did you implement what was in my answer and does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

In **macOS** there are several built-in ways to *watch* a *folder* and have something automatically done when the *contents* of the *watched folder* changes.

- The quickest and easiest way *may be* to use **Automator** to create a **Folder Action** *workflow*. However, in this use case I prefer the next method.
- There is also **Folder Actions Setup** in which one can attach an **AppleScript** *script* to a *watched folder* and or also manage it and or a **Folder Action** *workflow* created by **Automator**. This is where this answer will focus for creating the **Folder Action**.
- The least user friendly, without the use of a *third-party utility*, is manually creating a **Launch Agent** and using `launchctl` in **Terminal** to implement and manage it, and will not be covered herein.

Normally when watching a *folder*, the assigned *action/script* is triggered as the *contents* of the *watched folder* changes and it does its thing immediately and its done. It does not care if the **Folder Action** has not been triggered again to then do something else. As such, this presented an interesting look at how to e.g. send an **email** after e.g. 90 seconds from the time the last scanned *document* of the current scan batch is added to the *watched folder*, and essentially do nothing when *documents* are removed from it.

To that end, the solution presented herein has a few different working parts to get it set up. However, once its set up, its on autopilot thereafter...

- **AppleScript** *shell script* triggered by the **AppleScript** *script* attached to the **Folder Action**.
- **Terminal** to create the **AppleScript** *shell script* executable *file*.
- **TextEdit** to edit the **AppleScript** *shell script* executable *file*.
- **AppleScript Editor** to create the **AppleScript** *script* assigned to the **Folder Action**.
- **Folder Actions Setup**, a GUI *application* to configure and manage the **Folder Action** as needed.
- **Mail** to handle sending the email.

### **AppleScript** *shell script* executable *file*

- Create the **AppleScript** *shell script* executable *file* in **Terminal**.
- In **Terminal**, run the following *compound command*:

  ```
  f='scandone'; touch "$f"; open -e "$f"; chmod +x "$f"
  ```

<sup>• Hint: Copy and paste the *compound command* into **Terminal**, then press: <kbd>enter</kbd></sup>

- Then in the opened blank **scandone** *document*, in e.g. **TextEdit**, copy and paste the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown further below, into it.
- Then make appropriate edits to the *value* of each `property` at the top of the *script*, then save and close the **scandone** *document*.
- <sub>Note that by default the **AppleScript** *shell script* is created in the *root* of one's **Home** *folder*. As it will not be needed to run directly from **Terminal** it does not need to be in a location defined in the `PATH` passed to the *shell*. In **OS X Lion** I created a *folder* named `bin` within the *root* of my **Home** *folder* and moved the *script* there, even though it is not a *binary file*.</sub>

### **AppleScript** *script* to attach to the **Folder Action**

- In **AppleScript Editor**, create a *new document* adding the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown further below after the *example* **AppleScript** *code* used for the **AppleScript** *shell script*.

  - Setting `'/path/to/scandone'` to the actual **POSIX path** of the **AppleScript** *shell script* executable *file* created from the directions further above.
- Save the **AppleScript** *script* as, e.g. **Watch Scanning.scpt** in `~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts` noting that the `../Scripts/Folder Action Scripts` *folder* does not exist by default. If it does not already exist from previous usage, then just open **Terminal** and run the following *command*:

  ```
  mkdir -p -m 0700 "$HOME/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts"
  ```

<sup>• Hint: Copy and paste the *command* into **Terminal**, then press: <kbd>enter</kbd></sup>

### **Folder Actions Setup**

- Open **Folder Actions Setup** using one of the methods mentioned in the **Notes:** *section* below, starting at: To bring up **Folder Actions Setup** in **OS X Lion**
- Add the *watched folder* and **AppleScript** *script* using the **[+]** *button* on each side of the **Folder Actions Setup** *window*. Adding the *watched folder* from the left side, and the **AppleScript** *script*, e.g. **Watch Scanning.scpt**, from the right side of the *window*.
- On the **Folder Actions Setup** *window*, if the **[] Enable Folder Action** *checkbox* is unchecked, be sure to check it.

Assuming **Mail** is already configured with your **email** account and working normally, then you are all done and ready to start scanning. (Obviously do some testing first by just adding any old *file* into the *watched folder*, as if it was done by the scanner.)

### How It Works

When a *file* is added to the *watched folder* the **AppleScript** *script* attached to the *watched folder* in **Folder Actions Setup** runs the **AppleScript** *script*, which in this case spawns the **AppleScript** *shell script* executable *file* and then quits waiting for the **Folder Action** to be triggered again.

The spawned **AppleScript** *shell script* executable *file* then counts the number of *files* in the *watched folder*, waits for the e.g. 90 *seconds* and then counts the number of *files* in the *watched folder* again. Then if the *previous count* equals the *current count* the **AppleScript** *shell script* sends an *email* via **Mail**, the GUI *application*, not the *command line* `mail`, otherwise the *shell script* just terminates.

Obviously every time the **Folder Action** is triggered it is going to spawn another occurrence of the **AppleScript** *shell script*, however, in my testing I did not see this as an issue. It also was the easiest way I could think of to achieve the goal.

The thing to keep in mind is that the *total time* the *shell script* waits in-between checking the *file count* obviously has to be more than the *time* it takes to scan the *document* and save it to the *watched folder* and also includes an appropriate amount of buffer seconds so the *timing* works.

---

### **AppleScript** *shell script* executable *file*

***Example* AppleScript *code*:**

```applescript
#!/usr/bin/osascript

property waitTimeSeconds : 90
property watchedFolder : "/path/to/WatchedFolder"
property toName : "John Doe"
property toEmail : "johndoe@domain.com"
property |Subject| : "Finished Scanning"
property |Content| : "Finished Scanning"
property quitMail : false


set previousFileCount to countFilesInWatchedFolder()

delay waitTimeSeconds

set currentFileCount to countFilesInWatchedFolder()

if previousFileCount = currentFileCount then
    
    tell application "Mail"
        run
        set theMessage to ¬
            make new outgoing message with properties ¬
                {subject:|Subject|, content:|Content|}
        tell theMessage to ¬
            make new to recipient at end of ¬
                to recipients with properties ¬
                {name:toName, address:toEmail}
        send theMessage
    end tell
    
    if quitMail then
        delay waitTimeSeconds
        quit application "Mail"
    end if
    
end if

on countFilesInWatchedFolder()
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        return count files of folder watchedFolder
end countFilesInWatchedFolder
```

---

### **AppleScript** *script* to attach to the **Folder Action**

***Example* AppleScript *code*:**

```applescript
on adding folder items to
    do shell script "'/path/to/scandone' &>/dev/null &"
end adding folder items to

on removing folder items from
    return
end removing folder items from
```

---

### **Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was throughly tested in **Script Editor** (**AppleScript Editor** in **OS X Lion**) and as an **AppleScript** *shell script* and **Mail** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

As the **OS X Lion** system I tested this on is not connected to a **network**, I could not actually send the outgoing message in **Mail**, however the basic instructions work the same as it did in **macOS Catalina**. Meaning sans actually sending an **email** in **OS X Lion** when the *contents* of the *watched folder* changed, it did everything else programmed to do.

To bring up **Folder Actions Setup** in **OS X Lion**, it's not as easy as in testing in **macOS Catalina**. In **macOS Catalina**, bring up **Spotlight** and starting to type **Folder Actions Setup** makes it available to click to open it. This is not the case in **OS X Lion**. In **OS X Lion** I use **Terminal** and ran the following *command*:

```
open -a 'Folder Actions Setup'
```

In **OS X Lion**, it is located at: `/System/Library/CoreServices/Folder Actions Setup.app`

In **OS X Lion**, **Folder Actions Setup** can also be opened from the **Script** *menu* on the *menu bar* if so configure in **AppleScript Editor** > **Preferences…** by checking the **[√] Show Script menu in menu bar** *checkbox*, then from the **Script** *menu* on the *menu bar*, **Folder Actions**  > **Configure Folder Actions** opens **Folder Actions Setup**.

In **OS X Lion**, the predecessor to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**, in e.g. **macOS Catalina**, is **System Preferences** > **Universal Access** > **[] Enable access for assistive devices**. In my testing I did not need to have this checked. (YMMV)

<sup>In the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, if `property quitMail : false` is set `true` it will *quit* **Mail** after the same *value* of the *value* of `waitTimeSeconds`. Keep in mind that if the **email** *address* used for this **Folder Action** normally has a lot of traffic and **Mail** was not already opened, you may want to set the *value* for the `delay` *command* in the `if quitMail then` *block* manually and greater than the *value* set for `waitTimeSeconds`. This is to avoid a race condition between *receiving mail* and *sending mail* if the former occurs before the later. You obviously do not want **Mail** to *quit* before the *message* has been *sent* if a large amount is incoming slows down the *outgoing message*.</sup>

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>.